# Select Data from view vs Table of same name

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I have a database where a **view and a table have same name**, when I try to execute query

```
select * from XXXXXXXXX
```

from where is this data coming from, view or table? Is there any explicit declaration syntax to tell, to where from select the data?

**PS:** the DB owner is different so I can't change the structure of view/table or names either.

Comment: Are the duplicate view & table owned by the same owner?

Comment: @codeforester no owner is different, and duplicate would not be correct word for them in this context.

Comment: If you are running the query as a different user (and not the owner), then the query would work only if there is a public synonym sort of a thing (that's how Oracle does it).  You need to look at the definition of the synonym to find out which table or view it is pointing to.

Comment: @codeforester yes, i'm running query as different user... but my qs was in general... the view is pointing to the same table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects names are unique per owner, so the table and the view can't be defined for the same owner.
Qualify the table/view name with the right owner.

```
select * from table_owner.XXXXXXXXX

select * from view_owner.XXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: what about permissions, if i need data from view do i also need permission over the table, when view is referring the same table?

Comment: The view owner has select permissions on the table. You'll also need that.

Comment: If the view owner is dbo, you only need permssions on the view (anything it accesses in the same database need not be accessible.)